# Puppet nginx vhost with php support

Tags: php, nginx, puppet

I have created a custom resource to add vhosts with direct php support.
The vhost is created and the custom location is added but if i try it it downloads all the files instead of processing them.

What am i missing?
https://github.com/jfryman/puppet-nginx/ is the module that i use.

The pp file:

```
$full_web_path = '/var/www'

define web::nginx_php_vhost (
  $backend_port         = 9000,
  $php                  = true,
  $proxy                = undef,
  $www_root             = "${full_web_path}/${name}/",
  $location_cfg_append  = undef,
) {
  nginx::resource::vhost { "${name}.${::domain} ${name}":
    ensure                => present,
    listen_port           => 80,
    www_root              => $www_root,
    owner                  => 'evancauwenberg',
    group                  => 'www-data',
    mode                   => '0755',
    access_log            => "/var/log/nginx/${name}_access.log",
    error_log             => "/var/log/nginx/${name}_error.log",
    location_cfg_append   => {
      try_files => '$uri $uri/ =404'
    },
    index_files           => [ 'index.php' ],
  }

  if $php {
    nginx::resource::location { "${name}_root":
      ensure          => present,
      vhost           => "${name}.${::domain} ${name}",
      www_root        => $www_root,
      location        => '~ \.php$',
      index_files     => ['index.php', 'index.html', 'index.htm'],
      proxy           => undef,
      fastcgi         => "127.0.0.1:${backend_port}",
      fastcgi_script  => undef,
      location_cfg_append => {
        fastcgi_split_path_info => '^(.+\.php)(/.+)$',
        fastcgi_index => 'index.php',
        fastcgi_connect_timeout => '3m',
        fastcgi_read_timeout    => '3m',
        fastcgi_send_timeout    => '3m'
      }
    }
  }
}


web::nginx_php_vhost { "evert.be":
  www_root => "/var/www/evert.be",
}
```

The created vhost:

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           evert.be;

    index  index.php;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/evert_access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/evert_error.log;

  location ~ \.php$ {

    root  /var/www/evert/evert.be;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

    fastcgi_connect_timeout 3m;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3m;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3m;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;;
  }
  location / {

    root  /var/www/evert/evert.be;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}
```

Comment: So, is anything listening on `127.0.0.1:9000`?

Comment: evancauwenberg@dev01:/data/devops$ netstat -a | grep LISTEN  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:16001          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:9000          *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost:11211         *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:http                  *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN

Comment: doesn't look like anything listening on `:9000`. also. next time try `netstat -ant |grep :9000` or if you have `lsof` installed then `lsof -i :9000`